# Elasticache for Redis and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning about Redis and Elasticache and about how I can use them in conjunction with DynamoDB. My understanding is that if I query Redis and the info is not there, then the info would get retrieved from Dynamo and stored in Redis. However, I don't know if this is an automatic process or if this is something I have to do manually.
For instance I can ask Redis to get the value for key "User1" and depending on the result I can manually query Dynamo if needed and save the result in Redis. Or is this something done automatically?

Comment: AWS provides [DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) which is caching solution specifically dedicated to DynamoDB.

Comment: DAX seems to be a great solution! however, I need to use Redis for my project. I am using Socket.io and they seem to recommend to use Redis to pass events between nodes as speciffied here https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#Passing-events-between-nodes. I was just curious about the best way of using Redis, I am a newbie

Comment: in java there are libraries who work on annotations and does this work for you, (check in redis, if not there reads from db, put to redis, return value)